# I have a 24 track recorder. I want software that will let me download my tracks and mix the prerecorded tracks

Tags: audio-recording, software

I use a ZOOM 24 track recorder for recording my music. I want to download these tracks to a DAW and make adjustments to the sound, pitch and add effects. I don’t need a lot of plug in instruments just some effects and pitch corrections. Simple.

Comment: Any DAW will let you do this. I'd suggest getting one of the DAWs that has a free trial and see if you like it before buying.

Comment: Thanks Rory. That is what I was thinking too. Do you have any suggestions?  Something not too pricey?  This just for personal use to share with other band mates. 
Robby

Comment: https://ardour.org/ is free as free software but also as free beer. https://www.reaper.fm/ offers a free trial period and is not expensive if you choose to buy a licence.

Comment: Thank you for the information. It helps. I will check out both. 